# SQL -- Get items responsible for top 50% of sales

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
ITEM_SALES
    ITEM_NAME   SALES
    Item_name_1 5000
    ...
    Item_name_x 3
```

What I want to get is get the items that represent the top 50% of sales. So for example, if total sales was 10,000, just item_name_1 alone would represent 50% of sales.

I can obviously get total sales with:

```
select sum(sales) from ITEM_SALES.
```

...and then divide by 2 to get how many sales 50% of sales is.

However, I don't know how I'd go from there to getting the top items that represent 50% of sales.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using analytic functions:

```
select s.*
from (select item_name, sum(sales) as sumsales,
             sum(sum(sales)) over (order by sum(sales) desc) as cumesales,
             sum(sum(sales)) over () as totsales,
      from item_sales
      group by item_name
     ) s
where (cumesales - sumsales) < 0.5 * totsales;
```

The subquery calculates the sales for each item, as well as two other values:

- The cumulative sales, from highest to that item.
- The total sales.

The `where` clause then gets items up to and include the one that passes the 50% threshold.

Comment: This works perfectly, but I don't understand it.  How/why does cumesales work? How does ordering something affect the result of a sum function?

Comment: @Jeremy . . . I think you need to learn about Oracle's analytic functions.  You can start with the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_SALES ( ITEM_NAME, SALES ) AS
SELECT 'item_name_' || LEVEL, 50 - 3 * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 16;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ITEM_NAME,
         SALES,
         SUM( SALES ) OVER ( ORDER BY SALES DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS cumulative_sales,
         SUM( SALES ) OVER ( ORDER BY SALES DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS total_sales
  FROM   ITEM_SALES
)
WHERE cumulative_sales <= total_sales/2;
```

**Results**:

```
ITEM_NAME    SALES CUMULATIVE_SALES TOTAL_SALES
------------ ----- ---------------- -----------
item_name_1     50               50         440 
item_name_2     47               97         440 
item_name_3     44              141         440 
item_name_4     41              182         440 
item_name_5     38              220         440
```